# PHP Составление статистики, вопрос по массивам

Tags: php, массивы

Допустим есть N-ое кол-во массивов, содержащих идентификаторы пользователей.

Пример такого массива:

```
Array ( [0] => 241439019 [1] => 326313377 [2] => 289968681 [3] => 144237940 [4] => 174916220 )
```

Как запомнить людей попавших в эти массивы?

P.S. Идентификатор пользователя может попасть сразу в несколько массивов и это должно тоже запоминаться.

Ожидаемый результат вывода:

Пользователь: "Индефикатор", и "Количество раз, сколько индефикатор повторялся в массивах"

Comment: слить массивы  в один с помощью `array_merge` и посчитать повторы `array_count_values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Идентификатор пользователя может попасть сразу в несколько массивов*

Допустим, у вас есть три массива с айдишниками пользователей

```
$array_1 = array(241439019, 326313377, 289968681, 144237940, 174916220);
$array_2 = array(241439020, 326313378, 289968681, 144237940, 174916220);
$array_3 = array(241439019, 326313379, 289968680, 144237940, 174916220);
```

Тогда можно слить массивы и подсчитать количество повторяющихся элементов таким образом:

```
$array = array_merge($array_1, $array_2, $array_3);
$array = array_count_values($array);

array_walk($array, function($all, $id){
    echo "$id: $all<br>";
});
```

Результат:

```
241439019: 2
326313377: 1
289968681: 2
144237940: 3
174916220: 3
241439020: 1
326313378: 1
326313379: 1
289968680: 1
```

Comment: Используя такой способ, я смогу узнать количество "повторений айдишника" пользователя в этих массивах? (Мне это нужно для того чтобы определить сколько раз человек выполнил определенное действие. Для вывода рейтинга на главной странице сайта)

Comment: @CoffeeinTime да, в результате работы скрипта в переменной $id будет айдишник пользователя,а в $all количество посещений.

Comment: благодарю! буду пробовать.